# Attribute to Skip over a Method while Stepping in Debug Mode

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, attributes

Is there an attribute I can use on a method so that when stepping through some code in Debug mode the Debugger stays on the outside of the method?

Answer (score 192, accepted):

```
 [DebuggerStepThrough]
```

([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debuggerstepthroughattribute?view=netframework-4.7))

Comment: Thanks. I'm such a "Logger", the debugger skills are getting rusty.

Comment: What about an attribute for a property? [DebuggerStepThrough] is only valid on Classes, Structs, Constructors and Methods

Comment: Is there an inverse of this? I have a partial class linked to a generated partial class which has the [DebuggerStepThrough] attribute. I want to be able to step through my code without having to change VS's debugger properties.

Comment: Make sure to add `using System.Diagnostics;`

Comment: This doesn't step over the whole method (as asked in the question), it skips THROUGH it - so the debugger stops at the first method called within. So [DebuggerStepThrough] is only useful for very small methods which make no other calls.

Answer (score 14):

Not forgetting to add:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
```

Answer (score 8):

It's written `<DebuggerStepThrough>` in ***VB.NET***.

To use it just put on top of the method like :

```vb
<DebuggerStepThrough>
Private Sub form_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles form.Paint
     ' Picasso
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Answering in general (and to @Marchy in particular, even if 14 years after the fact).

A word of warning: Verbose code ahead. I don't like to have VB's `Imports` or C# `using` in my code because most of the example code I stumble upon almost invariably omit these declarations and just show the code, with no clue to the reader as from where the objects/classes/methods invoked come out.

In C#, you flag classes and functions as "debugger step thru" as follows:

```c#
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough]
class someClass {
    ...
}

[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough]
void someMethod (args...){
    ...
}
```

In VB, on the other hand, the syntax is almost the same; just use angle-brackets whenever you see C#'s square-brackets:

```vb
<System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough>
Friend Class someClass
    ...
End Class

<System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough>
Private Sub someMethod (args...)
    ...
End Sub
```

But what about properties, @Marchy says? These kick you in the face with an error* if you add the attribute to the property declaration itself. The solution is to add the attribute to the Getter/Setter themselves instead, as it affects code in contrast to declarations. In VB:

```vb
Public Property propertyName

    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough>
    Get
        ...
    End Get

    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough>
    Set (args...)
        ...
    End Set

End Property
```

Hope it helps.

*The error is: `Attribute 'DebuggerStepThroughAttribute' cannot be applied to '{propertyName}' because the attribute is not valid on this declaration type.`