# Attribute to ignore method in debugging -

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2012

I have a small logging method that I don't want to step through in normal debugging sessions in Visual Studio. I thought that there was an attribute to mark methods in a way that the debugger would automatically skip over them, but I can't find it in MSDN, and my googling hasn't turned up anything useful. Am I misremembering things? Is there an attribute that does this?

Comment: Can you not just hit F10 instead of F11?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggerstepthroughattribute.aspx

Comment: @JimmiTh, you should put that as an answer :)

Comment: Felt rather short for an answer - didn't feel like expanding on it. Besides, the "Related" list now shows a duplicate right at the top of the list. :-)

Comment: I guess we have different "related" lists? "VSIX extension for VS2012 not running when debugging" is mine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# - Attribute to Skip over a Method while Stepping in Debug Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/445276/c-sharp-attribute-to-skip-over-a-method-while-stepping-in-debug-mode)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is an attribute you can use called [DebuggerStepThrough (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggerstepthroughattribute.aspx):

```
using System.Diagnostics

...

[DebuggerStepThrough]
public void MyMethod() {
    ...
```

Comment: That's the one. Thank you! StackOverflow says "You can accept an answer in 5 minutes".